# JS: How to parse a nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

There is a JSON object:

```
var items = [{
              "item" : "A",
              "checked": false,
              "info": { "hello": "world" },
              "products": []
              },
              {
              "item" : "B",
              "checked": true,
              "info": { },
              "products": [1, 2, 3]
              }];
```

I need to parse each nested object and if there is additional objects, convert them to string.

For example, first object has another object into "info" key. And put the modified JSON Object in a new array.

I have tried like this:

```
var modifiedObj = [];

        items.forEach(function(item) {
            //get only values
            var val = Object.values(item);
            val.forEach(function(el) {
                //only if value is an object
                if (typeof el === 'object' && !Array.isArray(el)) {
                    //convert to str
                    var str = JSON.stringify(el, null, 2);
                    console.log(str);
                }
            });
        });
```

It works, but I cannot get how to put the modified JSON in a new array. So my ideal result is:

```
modifiedObj  = [{
              "item" : "A",
              "checked": false,
              "info": "{ 'hello': 'world' }", //String
              "products": []
              },
              {
              "item" : "B",
              "checked": true,
              "info": "{ }", //String
              "products": [1, 2, 3]
              }];
```

Comment: You need to stringify only part of the object? only if value is an object and not array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to iterate over an array and return a new array.
Since the elements of your array are objects, you'll need to use the `for...in` loop to iterate over the object.

```js
var items = [{
    "item": "A",
    "checked": false,
    "info": {
      "hello": "world"
    },
    "products": []
  },
  {
    "item": "B",
    "checked": true,
    "info": {},
    "products": [1, 2, 3]
  }
];

const modObj = items.map(item => {
  for (let prop in item) {
    if(typeof item[prop] === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item[prop])) {
      item[prop] = JSON.stringify(item[prop])
    }
  }
  return item;
})

console.log({ modObj })
```

PS: I'm not sure which properties you want stringified so I've kept the original `if` condition in my answer.

Links to read more about [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)